# Compute integral containing a matrix

Tags: probability, integration, matrices, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Let $\mathbf{H}= \begin{pmatrix}
   h_{11} & h_{12} \\
   h_{21} &  h_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$ and $P(\mathbf{H}$) the joint probability distribution of $\mathbf{H}$ given by: $e^{-(a+ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{2}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{2} b_{ij}|h_{ij}|^2  ) }$.
How to compute the following integrals:
 \begin{equation}
\int P(\mathbf{H}) d\mathbf{H}=1 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int P(\mathbf{H})|h_{ij}|^2 d\mathbf{H}=\sigma^2
\end{equation}
in order to calculate the coefficients $a$ and  $b_{ij} (\forall i$ and  $j)$.

Answer (score 0):

For the case where it is possible to diagonalize the Matrix in the Exponent this would be a good idea. As the Jacobian is Unity, you end up with ordinary Gaussian Integrals over the Eigenvalues for $(1)$. $(2)$ then can be generated by  differentiation of (1) with respect to $b_{ij}$

Comment: What do you mean by "diagonalize the Matrix in the Exponent" ? Could you please give me more details